# Integrating output y of continuous-time state-space representation wrt. time

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, control-theory

I have a state-space representation:

$$ \dot x(t) = A x(t) + B u(t) $$

$$ y(t) = C x(t) + D u(t) $$

and I would like to integrate $y(t)$ to get something like:

$$ \dot z(t) = \bar A z(t) + \bar B u(t) $$
$$ \int y(t) = \bar C z(t) + \bar D u(t) $$

I have not been able to find solutions to this online, so I came up with my own approach, but I am not sure that it is correct:

1. solving for $x(t)$:
   $$ \dot x(t) = A x(t) + B u(t) \implies x(t) = A^{-1} \dot x(t) - A^{-1} B u(t) $$
2. integrating $x(t)$:
   $$ \int x(t) = A^{-1} x(t) - A^{-1} B \int u(t) $$
3. integrating $y(t)$:
   $$ \int y(t) = C \int x(t) + D \int u(t) $$
4. substituting (2) into (3):
   $$ \int y(t) = C A^{-1} x(t) + (-C A^{-1} B + D) \int u(t) $$
5. defining:
   $$ z(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ \int u(t) \end{bmatrix} $$
   $$ \bar A = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
   $$ \bar B = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ I \end{bmatrix} $$
   $$ \bar C = \begin{bmatrix} C A^{-1} & -C A^{-1} B + D \end{bmatrix} $$
   $$ \bar D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

clearly $ \int y(t) $ is as in (4) and also:
$$ \dot z(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \dot x(t) \\ u(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A x(t) + B u(t) \\ u(t) \end{bmatrix} $$
right?

So my question(s) are:

1. is this solution valid or is there something that I have overlooked?
2. is there a better / more "correct" way to do this?
3. do you know of any references to this kind of integration of the output of a state-space representation?
4. clearly the new system cannot be integrated again using the same approach, due to $ \bar A $ being singular, is this a result of my (possibly flawed) solution? or is there perhaps some fundamental reason why it is not possible to twice-integrate the output of a state-space representation?

I am grateful for any constructive criticism and for answers that help further my understanding.

(I know that technically I am asking more that one question, but I don't feel that making them separate SE questions would make sense)

**EDIT:**

1. I suspect $ \bar D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} $ is wrong, and $\bar D$ should instead be some unknown constant matrix (the initial-conditions) right?
2. I corrected an error in step 3,4 and 5, pointed out to me by @KBS, there was a B which should have been D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the answer to your questions:

1. It seems that you have forgotten the initial conditions. Also, there is a term $B$ that should be $D$ in the second step and the next ones. Note that your approach is fully correct when the initial conditions are zero.

2, 3, and 4. The solution below simplifies your problems:

There is a simpler solution that does not require the invertibility of $A$. Just define the system

$$\dot{z}=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\C & 0\end{bmatrix}z+\begin{bmatrix}B\\D\end{bmatrix}u$$

where $z_1=x$ and $\dot{z}_2=y$. So, obviously, you get that $z_2(t)=\int_0^t y(s)ds$.

This procedure is called state-augmentation is used for the output regulation of linear systems where an integrator is added in order to regulate the output around a desired set-point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and please excuse my ignorance but there are some things I don't understand about your answer, please elaborate if possible: 1) you say that "there is a term B that should be D in the second step" why? I don't understand. in step 1 I am using the first line of the state-space to solve for x, and then in step 2 I integrate the result, I don't understand why D would be involved in this result?. 2) in your result you don't define C and D, but clearly z is not the same shape as x, so what is C and D ?.

Comment: ...3) I don't understand the line z2(t)=∫y(s)ds, where does the laplace transform of y come into the picture? (I assume s is the complex frequency/laplace variable?..) If you could elaborate on your solution (state-augmentation) it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aaaah I see an error now, in step 3 I have a B that should be D, I assume this is what you meant?

Comment: 1). One of your $B$ should be $D$ in step 3, not step 2. 2). The matrices $C$ and $D$ are the same as in your problem, so there is no reason to redefined them. 3) There is no Laplace transform here, $z_2$ is simply the integral of $y$ and $s$ is just an integration variable. Note that here it is important to use definite integrals in order to keep information on the initial conditions, which you lose in your calculations. For state-augmentation, this is well documented, look at any elementary book on the control of state-space systems.

Comment: 1) I noticed the problem, now corrected, thx. 2) but your $z$ has more rows that $x$ right? so how can $C$ be the same as in the original system? or do you mean that $\bar C$ is the same as in my solution?. 3) Okay I think I understand.. "For state-augmentation, this is well documented, look at any elementary book on the control of state-space systems" I have some books but neither contain any mentions of this, could you perhaps suggest one that does?.

Comment: sorry I understand the point about C now, I think your solutions makes sense to me now, thx!. but would still appreciate references that talk about this "state-argumentation".

Comment: 2) Check the dimensions. $z_1=x$ and $z_2=\int y$, so $z$ has dimension $n+m$ where $n$ is the dimension of $x$ and $m$ the dimension of $y$. The matrices are the same as in your original system. There is no problem here, write down the equations and verify the dimensions. 3) State-augmentation just means that we increase the size of state to accomplish something, here to compute the integral of the output. It is used a lot in regulation together with the Internal Model Principle (see the book of Dorf and Bisop for instance).

Comment: Thx again, makes sense to me now it was just a communication issue (on my part). What I meant is that in your solution you have $z = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \int y \end{bmatrix}$, $\bar A = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ C & 0 \end{bmatrix} $, $\bar B = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ D \end{bmatrix} $, $\bar C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \bar D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix} $.

Comment: Yes, I have the integral of the output in the extended state. This is more convenient as you do not need the invertibility of $A$.

Comment: makes sense, brilliant solution, didn't think of that.. I was just a bit confused about what $\bar C$ and $\bar D$ was in your solution, I understand now. Answer accepted, thx.